# How can I add x number of characters at the beginning of a string?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to add `x` number of `0` at the beginning of a string, the number of characters missing is stored on `$x`, but how can I add them into the string?

```
echo "$exampleString" | sed -i 's/^/0/'
```

`sed` works just fine, but the number of `0` must be typed manually instead of getting from a calculated variable

Comment: You can use the printf command to achieve this:

printf "%0*s" "$x" "$exampleString"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use printf as such:

````bash
x=5
string="test"
printf '%0*d%s\n' "$x" 0 "$string"```
````

Comment: This unnecessarily creates a subshell. `printf '%0*d%s\n' "$x" 0 "$string"` would do the trick at once.

Comment: I have edited my answer accordingly, thanks.

Comment: `x=0; printf '%0*d%s\n' "$x" 0 "$string"` ====> `0test`. if you truly want nothing appended when `"0"` is the input, then do  ==== ==== ==== ====  ====  ==== ==== ==== ==== `x=0; printf '%.*d%s\n' "$x" 0 "$string"` ===> `test` — it's a very subtle difference  between the width parameter and the precision one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple loop to calculate this.
Each step in the loop prepends a 0 to the result.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

text='example'
x=5
i=0
prefix='0'
until [ $i -eq $x ]; do 
  text="${prefix}${text}";
  ((i++))
done

echo "text is: $text"
```